# In a group of $265$ persons, $200$ like singing,.....

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I came across the following problem :

> In a group of $265$ persons, $200$ like singing,$110$ like dancing and $55$ like painting. If $60$ persons like both singing and dancing,$30$ like both singing and painting and $10$ like all three activities,Then what is the number of persons who like only dancing and painting?

My Attempt: Let us denote by $s,d,p$ for singing, dancing and painting respectively. Then the Venn diagram is as follows:  [image]

Here, $x$ is the number of persons who like only dancing and painting.  Since the total no. of persons is $265,$  we see from the diagram that

$265=\{120+50+10+20\}+\{50-x+x+25-x\} \implies 265=275-x$ which gives $x=10.$

Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: Hint:  Should the $60$ in your diagram refer to persons who like singing and dancing, or *only* singing and dancing? Similarly should the $30$ in your diagram be $20$?

Comment: Here ,$60$ refers to only singing and dancing...

Comment: But your question doesn't say that.  You have assumed it in the diagram.  Check!

Comment: I have found out my mistake...Here $60$ should be replaced by $50$ and $30$ should be replaced by  $20.$ thanks a lot @Macavity..

Comment: I see one issue with this problem: how many like none of the above?

Comment: @Mike I would say including ones who like nothing, $10 \le x \le 25$.

Answer (score 3):

The problem(s) is that the exercise tells you that 60 persons like singing and dancing but in your diagram you have that 60 persons like singing and dancing but **not** painting. Do you see the difference? The same goes for the persons like singing and painting.

Comment: Sir, I have edited my post..

Comment: ̈́@Sagarika: Now you are right!

Answer (score 0):

$$Total=S+D+P-SD-DP-PS+SDP\\
265=200+110+55-60-30-DP+10\\
65=165-80-DP\\
DP=20$$

Persons liking **only** dancing and painting$=DP-SDP=20-10=10$